# How to overwite django password_reset_confirm page?

Tags: html, django

I am a new Django developer. I am trying to overwrite django password_reset_confirm.html page with the below HTML file(change_pwd.html).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" href="{% static "icon/tab_logo.png"%}">
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="{% static "web/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
      <link href="{% static "web/src/css/login.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="{% static "web/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>     
   </head>
   <body >   
      <div class="vertical-center">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class=" col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                  <div id="loginbox" >
                     <h1 class="text-center title">Change Password</h1>
                     </br></br>                          
                     <form id="passwordform" role="form" method="post" action=".">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" >                          
                           <input type="password" class="pwd" name="new_password1" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off">                                        
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" >
                           <input type="password" class="pwd" name="new_password2" placeholder="repeat password" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top:10px" >
                           <!-- Button -->
                           <input id="btn-change-pwd" class="btn btn-primary btn_extend " type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have also overwritten the project's Urls.py as below:

```
path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name' : 'change_pwd.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

When I reset password, the page is redirected to admin/templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html page and then displays below message:

> The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.

Based on admin/templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html, this error happens whenever reset_password link is not valid. When I remove {'template_name' : 'change_pwd.html'} from the Url, it works. But I do not know how to fix this error in change_pwd.html.

Answer (score 0):

Django user templates must be inside a registration folder. 
Ex: templates/registration/change_pwd.html
Change

```
path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name' : 'change_pwd.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

to

```
path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name' : 'registration/change_pwd.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```